# Single word describing something "outside of oneself"

Tags: single-word-requests

ie.:  The idea was "(blank)".  It didn't come from myself, it was divine inspiration, dumb luck, etc.

or maybe: My essence/spirit was outside my body.  It was "(blank)".

Comment: In your first example, it's possible you mean **ex machina**, which is used in describing stories, etc. In your second utterly and totally unrelated example, you're talking about a dualist view of life (a "religious", not "scientific" view, if you will). It's also possible you're just looking for "supernatural" which is a synonym for "spooky".

Comment: The term "disembodied" might fit somehow.

Comment: @Jordan Smith - if you were an actualist, you'd call it "pure intent". cf. https://www.actualists.org/pure-consciousness-experiences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two that immediately spring to mind would be [external](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/external):

> 1. Outside of something; on the exterior.

And [extrinsic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extrinsic):

> 1. external, separable from the thing itself, inessential
> 2. not belonging to, outside of

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the second part, if you truly felt your spirit had left your body, there is a *set phrase* for this: **out-of-body experience**.

People who have **near-death experiences** (another *set phrase*) often report out-of-body sensations as a part of the experience.

People who are able to intentionally induce an out-of-body experience, wherein they "travel" to other places, are practicing what is sometimes called **astral projection**.

See also **remote viewing** which has been a recurrent topic discussed by Art Bell on his radio show **Coast to Coast am**.  Here is one such episode:

http://www.coasttocoastam.com/guest/dames-major-ed/5589

Answer (score 1):

ecstasis or ekstasis: to be or stand outside oneself, a removal to elsewhere 
from ek- "out" and stasis "a stand" 
a form of ecstasy

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [cite](/help/referencing) any sources you've used in this answer.

Comment: I'm rolling this back to the answer you had. If you want to delete your answer you will probably need to register your account, then a delete button should show up at the bottom of this post. Alternatively, you should be able to flag with the "in need of moderator intervention" flag and tell the mods to delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea was ***uncanny***

Though the title of the OP merely asks for a single word that would describe something “outside of oneself,” the body of the OP is somewhat more elaborate and describes this something as of "divine inspiration, dumb luck, etc." For this reason, and despite Parthian Shot's apt and officially selected answer ("*external*"), I would also suggest the adjective "**uncanny**" as a suitable descriptor for the experience of something unusual, or even preternatural, whose origins lie outside of the normal, day-to-day, self.

> [**uncanny**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=uncanny+definition&gws_rd=ssl)
>    *adjective*: strange or mysterious, especially in an unsettling way. "an *uncanny* feeling that she was being watched"
>
> **synonyms**: eerie, unnatural, unearthly, preternatural, supernatural, otherworldly

(Google)

Answer (score 0):

The word for something that arises outside oneself but affects or becomes parts of oneself is "exogenous."  This seems to fit with the "The idea was" part of the question.

"External" merely means on the exterior and given no sense of the thing outside being intimately connected to the inside, which seems to the thrust of the "or maybe" part of the question.  "Extrinsic" is good except for the connotation it has of "inessential," which the word gets from its antonym "intrinsic."

If you're content with a technical term specifically tied to the spiritual, then there's always "ectoplasmic."

Answer (score 0):

*Extracorporeal* has the exact meaning of something being outside one's body.

Merriam-Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extracorporeal):

> extracorporeal
>
> ```
> adjective ex·tra·cor·po·re·al \-kȯr-ˈpȯr-ē-əl\
> ```
>
> Definition of EXTRACORPOREAL
>
> :  occurring or based outside the living body "the heart-lung machine maintains >extracorporeal circulation during heart surgery"